# Computation of a Hessian and a Gradient

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, hessian-matrix

Let $J(x,y)=x^2 -xy +y^2+3x-2y+1$ be a function defined on $E = R^2$.

Gradient : $ (2x -y +3, 2y-x-2)$

Hessian :  $\binom{2  \ 0}{ 0 \ 2 }.$

the value of $a$ is : $y=3+2x \implies 2*(2y-x-2) +2x =4y-2x-4 \implies y=0.5x -1$

So  i'm lost  $a=\frac{5}{4};\frac{-14}{4}$??

I can not calculate the Hessian and deduce a local minimum point and is this a strict minimum, thanks

Comment: What is $a$? A stationary point? Please update your question

Comment: So ` $J(x,y) - J(\frac{5}{4};\frac{-14}{4})$ >0 so i  deduce a local minimum

Comment: A friendly piece of advice from your friendly moderator: Spend a while browsing our site, may be concentrate on your favorite tags. You will quickly learn what is expected from questions. Oh, and Do. Not. Repost. Then the moderator will stop being friendly. Editing the older versions of the question into shape is THE ONLY WAY.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a stationary point of this function and are trying to figure out what kind of stationary point it is. However, you've run into a few problems.

1) To find the stationary point, you need to solve $\boldsymbol\nabla J = 0$. You've got the correct expression for the gradient, so now you just need to solve the system
\begin{eqnarray}
3 + 2x - y &=& 0\\
-2-x+2y &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
whose solution is not $(x,y) = (5/4,-14/4)$.

2) To determine what kind of stationary point, you need to first evaluate the Hessian ($\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\nabla J$) at that point. You might want to check your calculation on that one, as it is not $[(2,0)(0,2)]$ (though you are correct that it is constant).

3) Once you have the Hessian, since this is a function of two variables, you simply need to check its determinant and the sum of its diagonal entries. A negative determinant is a saddle point; a positive determinant and positive sum of diagonal entries is a local minimum; and a positive determinant and negative sum of diagonal entries is a local maximum.